# Start a Powershell script with a variable through Javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell, cookies

I'm working on a tool to print out etiquettes. First the user has to enter his Active Directory login which is then stored in a COOKIE. Then I want to run a Powershell script on the server with this COOKIE variable so that the Powershell is executed on the computer of the logged in user. It is not possible to set a default printer on the server because this has been blocked by the company.
My question now is how to execute a Powershell script on the server with the saved user in the cookie.

Thank you very much for your answers.

```
      <script>
         
          function print() {

          Sys.OleObject["WScript.Shell"].Run("powershell -file C:\test\ticketprint.ps1");

        }

      </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the SQL (or more specifically SQL Server) has to do with the question, however, your SQL is wide open to injection attacks and **needs** to be fixed...

Comment: The user is checked from the database when logging in and is stored in the cookie, the website is an internal page and only certain people have access to it.

Comment: But you aren't asking abott SQL Server, noah, that is my point. You're using SQL Server to store the cookies, sure, but that isn't related to the question; the question is how to run a Powershell script from Javascript. Though, like I mentioned, you ***need*** to parametrise your SQL statement; SQL Injection is fatal, dangerous, and inexcusable.

Comment: Okey thank you very much larnu, now I understand.